# Spring WS client in asynchronous mode (how to read response?)

Tags: java, spring, web-services, soap, jms

I need to implement WS client that works asynchronously with soap webservice. I realize that i need to configure my `WebServiceTemplate` to use `JmsMessageSender` and to use jms queue as URI. 
But how do i get a response from "response queue" after webservice will proccess my request? I expected to have some callback or listener registered that will handle response message. But i can't find any information about it?

Comment: You cannot. See https://jira.spring.io/browse/SWS-914 and https://jira.spring.io/browse/SWS-882. `WebServiceTemplate` is only synchronous it isn't fire-and-forget and not async. Using JMS as a transport doesn't change that. If that is good enough just specify the reply queue in the `jms:` url with `replyToName` else a temporary queue will be created instead.

Comment: @M.Deinum So if i need to send soap to queue from spring, what is a best approach? Use jmsTemplate and marshall request object to soap and place it in jms message?